# How to convert XMFLOAT3 to const float *pData?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, directxmath

I have the following code:

```
XMFLOAT3 normalized_direction = XMVector3Normalize(direction);
pEffect->GetVariableByName("g_CameraDirection")->AsVector()->SetFloatVector(normalized_direction);
```

I want to pass XMFLOAT3 in const float *pData ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the first entry of your vector:

```
... ->SetFloatVector(&normalized_direction.x);
```

Comment: But what if he asks for Matrix?

Comment: The first element of a `XMFLOAT4X4` is `_11`, so reference that.

Comment: I needed the first element of anything, my question doesn't make sense, now I understand thank you for your help.